# Menu dropdown with css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm finding script that can make my menu like

[image]

I find some script but sub menu will align left, not like this.

```
<div id="menu-container">
              <ul class="menu" style="background-color:#1DBAA5;">
                <li  style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px" class="level1 nav-2-<?php echo $demmn; ?> first dropdown" >
                        <a href="#" style="color:#fff">
                            <span>TEST</span>
                        </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="background:#111;width:600px">
                        <li>
                          <a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

My css

```
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
left: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

 .menu{
  max-width: 600px;
  }

  .menu>li{
  }

.dropdown-menu li {
 width: 30%;
 display: inline-block;

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this .It will be align with in left

I was change the value of `<ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="background:#111;width:475px">` for same sizing.you change as your wish.

**They will be use for left position alignment**

```
.dropdown-menu .sub-menu {
left: 100%;
position: absolute;
}

.menu{
 max-width: 600px;
 padding-top:10px;
 }

.menu>li{
 display: inline;
 padding-left: :20px;
 }

 .dropdown-menu li {
  width: 30%;
  display: inline-block;

  }
```

```html
<div id="menu-container">
              <ul class="menu" style="background-color:#1DBAA5;">
                <li  style="padding-left:10px;padding-top:10px" class="level1 nav-2-<?php echo $demmn; ?> first dropdown" >
                        <a href="#" style="color:#fff">
                            <span>TEST</span>
                        </a>
                      <ul class="dropdown-menu" id="menu1" style="background:#111;width:475px">
                        <li> <a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>

                        <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#" style="color:#fff">TEST</a></li>
                      </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This part `.dropdown-menu .sub-menu` has not been included on your code